# coc.nvim build/index.js not found please install dependencies and compile coc.nvim by npm ci

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc

[image]

how to fix this guys? its my first time to use nvim.. vscode is so laggy on my laptop

Comment: Please don't share textual data as an image. Instead, [edit] and paste that error message. Btw, did you install dependencies and compile coc.nvim? Did you follow its [installation instructions?](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Install-coc.nvim) I'd recommend any new user to start without plugins and only install any once you're comfortable with the editor itself.

Comment: Did you run `:PlugInstall` at all? BTW, your mapping of `<C-T>` shadows the built-in `:help CTRL-T`. And why does the comment behind *multiple cursors* (a feature you don't even need if you can use Vim's built-ins) say it uses *CTRL-N* when you map `<C-N>` to `:NERDTree` five lines below? One of them is not going to work. Start slow.

Comment: Could you give us information about your OS (e.g. Linux, Windows, macOS)?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to verify that:

- [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en) installed
- That the `node` command is available (that the `PATH` environment variable contains the `node` executable folder)
- [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm) is installed (this is probably not a must but I recommend it)

More information in the [coc.nvim installation instructions](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Install-coc.nvim)